# Proof for $4\sin(2x)\cos(2x) + 2 = 2\sin(4x) + 2$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone tell me step by step why those are the same?

$$4\sin(2x)\cos(2x) + 2 = 2\sin(4x) + 2$$

Thank you!

Comment: Just use sin2x=2sinxcosx , and if you want to prove this identity recall sin(x+y)=sinxcosy+cosxsiny and replace y with x

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
If we replace $$x$$ by $$2x$$ we get $$\sin(4x)=2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$ and $$4\sin(2x)\cos(2x)=2\sin(4x)$$

Comment: These are both the same equality...